Loading and processing internet radio mp3 stream in python
I'd like to write a python program, that is loading a internet-radio mp3 stream, doing some processing to the data and plays the audio stream from the computer.
Question: is there a python library that can convert audio stream mp3 data (unfinished chunked) to pure audio, while informing about the partial leftovers of unconverted mp3-data from next mp3 frames for later processing when new chunk of mp3 arrives?
I mean streaming of audio does not retrieve mp3 complete chunks from internet, instead fixed-size chunks. So there are leftovers that have to be processed later.
This is my code, it works fine, but I would have to keep the streaming audio forever and I can't throw away the processed data, so it will grow forever.
import pyaudio
import requests
import soundfile

# minimal example
radio_stream_buffer = bytearray()
stream_url = 'http://live.slovakradio.sk:8000/FM_256.mp3'
converted_frames = 0

CHUNK_SIZE = 32768
request = requests.get(stream_url, stream=True, timeout=10)
iterator = request.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE)

pya = pyaudio.PyAudio()
audio_stream = pya.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32, channels=2, rate=44100, output=True)

while True:
    block = next(iterator)
    radio_stream_buffer.extend(block)

    # convert via file, as for older libsnd versions doing it via io.BytesIO fails
    with open('buffer.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(radio_stream_buffer)
    # skip from frame we have read last to get only most recent chunk
    data, samplerate = soundfile.read('buffer.mp3', start = converted_frames, dtype='float32')
    num_read_frames = len(data)
    if num_read_frames == 0:
        continue

    # write data frames to audio output
    converted_frames += num_read_frames
    audio_stream.write(data.tobytes())

Sidenote: sound output in the example is choppy, because in reality the processing has to be done in threads to avoid audio playback delays causing choppy sounds.
